# UIWindow's makeKeyAndVisible and background task

Tags: ios, ios7, uiwindow

I've add the background task feature to my application. Here is my app delegate

```
// AppDelegate.m

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [self setWindow:[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]];
    [self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    if (application.applicationState != UIApplicationStateBackground) {        
        // Application is launch in because user tap the app icon or from springboard

        if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:)]) {
            [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum];
        }
    } else {
        // Application is launch in background mode
    }

    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initByDevice];
    [self.window setRootViewController:rootViewController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {

    [[DataManager instance] updateDataWithMaxAttempt:5 block:^(BOOL success, NSArray *newData) {
        if (success) {
            if ([newData count] > 0) {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
            } else {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
            }
        } else {
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
        }
    }];
}
```

And this is my root view controller

```
// RootViewController.m

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"Did appear");
    // Do something that I want it to happen only when the application is visible to user
}
```

When the user tap the app icon, application works like what I expected. I see "Did appear" in console and stuff is happening after that like I expected.

But when the application awake to perform background task (which not visible to user) the `RootViewController's` `viewDidAppear` still getting call because of this line

```
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

By calling makeKeyAndVisible, it makes `RootViewController` visible even though it's only awake for background task. To fix this, I have to move this line to `applicationDidBecomeActive`

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

As a result, the `RootViewController's` `viewDidAppear` now being call only when the application is  in foreground (visible to user). But, my concern is, when application is in device memory (either active or inactive) `applicationDidBecomeActive` will be call several times.

- user launch app
- application become active again from springboard
- device unlock
- finish call

Is there any issue if I call `UIWindow's` `makeKeyAndVisible` several times during the application life cycle?

Comment: I think `UIAlertView` or `UIActionSheet` will call this method because the key window is changed when they are showing. I don't think it is a good way to call `[self.window makeKeyAndVisible]` in `applicationDidBecomeActive` because at that time there maybe a `UIAlertView` shows.

Comment: @KudoCC Thanks for your info, I never know about this before! Do you know what will happen if I show an alertview --> lock device --> unlock it --> call [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]?

Comment: It's hard to say, it is a undefined action, you can have a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily ensure that `makeKeyAndVisible` only happens once: wrap it.

```
if (!self.window.keyWindow) {
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible;
} else if (self.window.hidden) {
    self.window.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Henri, I did apply something similar to your answer. By the way, do you know what will happen if I call makeKeyAndVisible multiple times? (Like the comment from KudoCC in my original question, he said that UIAlertView and UIActionSheet did call makeKeyAndVisible too)

Comment: I think it depends on the context. Call it twice in a row and it probably won't do anything. I'm not at my desk right now but it's easily checked. In any case I prefer making sure I need it myself without relying on the API logic innards. Hence the simple wrap.